# How to make computer return from standby mode

Tags: windows, scheduling, sleep

I would like my computer to do specific tasks periodically or at a specific time.

Such as:

- to wake up each 15 minutes, connect to the Internet, check e-mail, beep (if there is unread mail), then go standby again
- to wake up at 8 am and play music

In the best case, it should be asleep and therefore, silent and going low-power.

It's no problem to make it connect or check the mail, but how to make it wake up ... ?
Do you happen to know the software to achieve this or windows API to use ?
I feel like there is one, but I failed to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WakeUpOnStandBy](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/download.php?what=WOSB) (Windows)

Answer (score 2):

- [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(VS.85).aspx)
- [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289(VS.85).aspx)
- [SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201(VS.85).aspx) to enter the suspended state.
- [CancelWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681985(VS.85).aspx)

More info for example [here](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/faq.php?what=wosb).

Other alternatives require some more hardware support - like for example the Wake-On-Lan feature or IPMI.

Answer (score 1):

Some computers have options like what you want in BIOS. I don't believe there's any way without BIOS support. Once your computer is asleep there's no programmatic way for it to wake up, since any such program is asleep...